# Create categorical column based on row records

Tags: python, pandas

i have a text file with this particular format

```
 8493   RR44   
  0.140064597       3.03221084E-02  0.332000017    
  0.143124133       2.99523491E-02  0.333307326     
 8493   RR47   
  0.140064597       3.03221084E-02  0.332000017    
  0.141788140       2.88347229E-02  0.332700878
```

with first, second, and third column as X, Y, and Z record and 8493 and RR44 and RR47 is the category of those records that stands for Event and Station ID, and Each category might have different length of records.

I have loaded my text file to pandas dataframe

```
ray = pd.read_csv('ray_test.txt',sep='\t',header=None)
ray.columns = ['X','Y','Z']
print(ray.head)
```

and it came out well, here is the output.

```
              X         Y         Z
0   8493.000000      RR44       NaN
1      0.140065  3.03E-02  0.332000
2      0.143124  3.00E-02  0.333307
3  8493.000000      RR47       NaN
4      0.140065  3.03E-02  0.332000
5      0.141788  2.88E-02  0.332701
```

But i want to somehow group or create a category of the data based on the Station ID and Event like this

```
              X         Y         Z        Event    ID
0      0.140065  3.03E-02  0.332000  8493.000000  RR44 
1      0.143124  3.00E-02  0.333307  8493.000000  RR44 
2      0.140065  3.03E-02  0.332000  8493.000000  RR47 
3      0.141788  2.88E-02  0.332701  8493.000000  RR47
```

But i don't want to loop over entire records, is there some way to group my dataframe to the desired dataframe? Any kind of help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are they all sep by two rows of data. Trying to find the common element here.

Comment: i don't think so, because each station could have different length of data recorded, i just took a small subset of the data

Comment: @azharharisandi On what criteria you want to identify the different set of rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have your df `ray`, you can loop through the rows and check if the `Z` col is `NaN`. If yes, store the value of `X` and `Y` in the subsequent rows until you get another row with `Z` equal to `NaN`.

```
for idx, row in ray.iterrows():
    if pd.isnull(row['Z']):
        event, id = row['X'], row['Y']
    else:
        ray.at[idx, 'event'] = event
        ray.at[idx, 'id'] = id

ray = ray[ray['Z'].isnull()==False]
print(ray)
```

Output:

```
          X       Y         Z   event    id
1  0.140065  0.0303  0.332000  8493.0  RR44
2  0.143124    0.03  0.333307  8493.0  RR44
4  0.140065  0.0303  0.332000  8493.0  RR47
5  0.141788  0.0288  0.332701  8493.0  RR47
```

Note that this heavily assumes the `Z` column as null for the rows you want in the event and id column. Let me know if this works.

Comment: sorry for my inactivity, i appreciate your answer. I had solved the problem with some sort of same logic as yours, but with messier code, yours is clearly more readable, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it was helpful